# The qt creator IDE doesn't support multiline regex search

Tags: regex, qt, qt-creator

I used the "Search Results" window to search for some contents of "CMakeLists.txt", and I selected the "Use regular expressions", and the regex is

```
 (add_executable|add_library|target_link_libraries)\s*\(.*mylib.*\)
```

but `\s` of regex doesn't match `\n`. I changed `\s` to `.`, it didn't match. I added `(^m)` in front of the regex, but it still didn't match.

Is this a bug of Qt Creator IDE? Can I use another tool or plugin of Qt Creator supporting multi-line searching?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I came across this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1011) about precisely this. I recommend that everybody crates an account and upvotes that bug report or we are not getting this anytime soon.

Comment: Maybe `(\s|\n)` instead of `\s` will help. (Windows files may have `\r\n`! So `(\s|\r?\n)` will be needed).

Comment: In VS Code, to make `\s` work, we can just add `\n{0}` at the start of the regex. Can you check here?

Answer (score -1):

It's very common for regex engines to be unable to handle multi-line matches irrespective of `\n` matching or the `/m` modifier.  More unusual for them to handle them successfully, in my experience.  You're probably out of luck.

Comment: For the record: It has nothing to do with the regex engine, but with the data fed to it - more often than not the data/files are processed line by line, as is the case here.